# Run Django Custom Command locally?

Tags: python, django, heroku, automation, cron

Owing to not having a Credit Card, can't use heroku's task scheduler.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduling-custom-django-management-commands

This site talks about running the custom command locally via cli. Is it possible to automate this cli "script" so it runs every day? I know it's possible in normal python scripts but unsure about this one. All leads appreciated thanks a lot.

Comment: You can schedule a cronjob: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: not sure about heroku but normally with Django you would use Celery as scheduler (+async)

Answer (score 0):

I frequently call Django management commands using cron. Here's an example of a Django management command that gets run every five minutes; note that it takes two steps, activating the `venv`, then running the actual command as you would from a CLI:

```sh
*/5 * * * * source /var/www/my-site-develop/venv/bin/activate && python /var/www/my-site-develop/manage.py my_custom_command --settings=config.settings.prod
```

Good luck!